# Is it possible to return a default value if one of the record return null

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am new in SQL. Now I want to handle the case that if I am selecting for the Name and Unit in table of fruit where `Name` in `('apple','orange','banana')`.

However, there is no item called `banana` in database yet and I want to have a default value for `banana` like

```
Name         Unit 

apple         10

orange        20

banana         0
```

How can I do this instead of just getting

```
Name         Unit

apple         10

orange        20
```

Can I do this by using `Union`?

Comment: Furthermore information, actually I am doing this with my C# program. Users can search the Unit of the item by using string [] and now I want to have a default value if there is a item can't be search.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a union:

```
select  t.name, unit
from table t
union all
select 'banana', 0;
```

Note that if `banana` is in the table, then you will get a duplicate row.

EDIT:

If you don't want duplicate records, I would suggest a `full join` approach.

```
select coalesce(t.name, mine.name) as name, coalesce(t.unit, 0) as unit
from (select 'banana' as name
     ) mine full outer join
     table t;
```

Comment: You could always make that a derived table and select name, sum(unit)

Comment: Thanks Gordon! I have tried your suggestion. It works find. However I don't want duplicate record in this case. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Gordon's solution above with the addition to avoid duplicate rows for banana.

```
select  t.name, unit
from table t
union all
select 'banana', 0
where not exists
(select name from table where name = 'banana');
```